# Discrepancy between linux man page and implementation of mmap

Tags: linux, ubuntu, man, mmap

I am trying to compile a program that requires the mmap(2) to support the flag `MAP_SYNC`, but my compiler reports that no such thing exists. Now, I manually verified the header file for mmap and found out that flag's absent. My system's man page also says that mmap doesn't have any such flag, but the man page available [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) says that the flag exists linux kernel 4.15+ which [is true](https://docs.pmem.io/getting-started-guide/system-requirements).

I'm already on kernel 5.0.0 and don't understand why the flag is absent, is there a way to fix this?

My system:

```bsh
$ uname -a
Linux hostname 5.0.0-29-generic #31~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Sep 12 18:29:21 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.  
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS                                                                                                                       Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
```

Thanks!

Comment: The version of the running kernel (as reported by `uname`) has nothing to do with the version of the development packages which provide the C headers. You can define that flag yourself to the actual value, guarding it inside an `#ifndef MAP_SYNC` ... `#endif`.

Comment: @mosvy I see thanks, is there a way I can update the headers?